# Is there a way to retrieve multiple random values from a list?

Tags: python, discord.py

I’m coding a discord bot in discord.py and I want people to be able to retrieve multiple different random values from a list. Here’s an example

```
list = [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’, ‘e’]

@client.command
async def pick(ctx, amount):
    await ctx.send(f’{random.choice(list)}’)
```

I’m getting stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) which does exactly what you want.

> ```py
> random.sample(population, k)
> ```
>
> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.